# Using Sed to get all characters between opening and closing characters

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed

I'm trying to use sed to get some characters between an opening and a closing character. These opening and closing characters could be braces e.g. { and }, etc. In my specific case, the opening character is `=` and the closing character is the end of the line.

In PHP, I had a regex that usually worked for me: `([^\^]*?)`. However, being that sed uses the POSIX-BRE flavour, I do not believe this will work.

The string I'm using the regex on could be something like this: `password=mailPASSWORD`. mailPASSWORD could contain regular alphabet characters as well as special characters.

So I want to replace mailPASSWORD and put my own password.

```
sed -i -r "s/password[ ]*=[ ]*([pattern_goes_here])/password=mypassword/" /myfile
```

I'd appreciate some assistance.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After looking at other alternatives to sed, I found out that perl is actually a much better tool for this sort of thing. And being that my Regular Expression knowledge is pretty much perl-based it looks like the better way to go.

Here's how I would solve the same problem:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/password *= *[^\n]*/password=mypassword/" /myfile
```

Since I'm doing stuff line by line it just make things a lot easier to script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case:

```
sed -i -r -e 's/password *= *[^\t ]*/password=mypassword/' /myfile
```

For the more general case, if the end delimiter is a character, let's say `x`, you simulate this:

```
.*?x
```

with this:

```
[^x]*x
```

For multi-character end-delimiters it gets more complicated, but that's the basic idea: instead of non-greedy matching, create a pattern that matches everything *but* the end-delimiter.

Comment: The end delimiter is a new line or space or tab. In PHP I would do something like this `password[ ]*=[ ]*([^\^]*?)[ \n\t]*`. Not sure how I achieve the same in a POSIX-BRE fashion?!

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh Your question says "the closing character is the end of the line". You didn't mention anything about tabs or spaces being end delimiters. See update to my answer. You don't need to exclude `\n` as sed is line-based, and so newlines are effectively excluded for you.

Answer (score 2):

**With `sed`:**

```
[jaypal:~] sed 's/\(.*[^=]=\)[[:alnum:]]\+/\1mypassword/' <<< password=mailPASSWORD
password=mypassword
```

**With `awk`**

```
[jaypal:~] awk -F"=" '{$2="mypassword";print $1"="$2}' <<<  password=mailPASSWORD
password=mypassword
```

Comment: +1 For the `sed` case, I would include the `=` in the \1 backreference so you don't need to explicitly type it in the replacement text again

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX, I agree, thats the right approach. Have updated the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. Isn't `:alnum:` just digits and characters i.e. `[\w]` equivalent?

Comment: Ya, that is correct. This was just a sample solution for you to add more magic as per your needs. For instance, you can throw `[:punct:]` in the mix which accepts all punctuation characters. This might [help](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch03_02.htm)

Comment: @Jaypal Thanks. This information will really come in handy later. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'someotherpassword=xxx password = mailPASSWORD_with_an_=_sign another=yyy' |
sed 's/^\(.*\<password\s*=\s*\)\S*/\1mypassword/' 
someotherpassword=xxx password = mypassword another=yyy
```

If you don't want to preserve the white space either side of the `=` sign, then:

```
echo 'someotherpassword=xxx password = mailPASSWORD_with_an_=_sign another=yyy' |
sed 's/^\(.*\<password\)\s*=\s*\S*/\1=mypassword/' 
someotherpassword=xxx password=mypassword another=yyy
```

If the line only contains one password assignment then:

```
echo 'password = mailPASSWORD_with_an_=_sign' |
sed 's/\(=\s*\)\S*/\1mypassword/' 
password = mypassword
```

Or without white space:

```
echo 'password = mailPASSWORD_with_an_=_sign' |
sed 's/\s*=.*/=mypassword/' 
password=mypassword
```